# OpenVPN Tunneling Facebook/Gmail App

Tags: openvpn

I recently downloaded the OpenVPN app and I have it setup to connect to a server at my house and all of my HTTP(S) traffic is tunneled through the connection. I have confirmed this by going to ipchicken.com and it shows the correct public IP. Under the OpenVPN settings I have the "use system proxy" box checked. My question is does that pertain to the Facebook and Gmail apps as well? I would assume the apps are just using HTTPS to connect and then display them but wasn't 100% sure.

On a side note, for some reason every time I connect to my VPN on the cell network, it pushes me my correct 192.168.1.0/24 route that my server is handing out but it also pushes a 10.109.105.209/255.255.255.240 route. This is not defined anywhere in my setup and doesn't show up when I connect to my VPN through another WiFi network. It is solely linked to the cell network. Everything still works fine but was curious why it did this.

Thanks in advance,

Eric